# Geckodriver is in path but vscode doesn't recognize it

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

[image]

As you can see it is in the Python folder but it still says this

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver'
executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: Trying to eliminate the obvious: the Python version VS Code is using is the same as where you've place the executable?

Comment: Also, although I don't think it's likely: that Python directory may not be in your PATH.